developing image uploads with ckeditor 4
enter image description here
hello can anyone help me.. I'm making a create form by uploading an image in ckeditor 4 but when I click the image button there is no upload button only the image info, link, advanced display appears can anyone help how can I display the upload tab then I can choosefile and send it to servers?
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.22.1/full/ckeditor.js"></script>

  <script>
   CKEDITOR.replace('content', {
      filebrowserUploadUrl: "{{ route('pages.image').'?_token'.csrf_token() }}",
      filebrowserUploadMethod: 'form'
      });
   </script\>

